# how to return a data from http call in angular 2 when the call is success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular

Take this function as example:

```
getSessionInfo() {
     this._http.get(someCorrectUrlHere)
     // Don't know what this map function do
    .map(res => res.json())
    // Don't know what this subscribe function do
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.response.statusCode === 200) {
           ** the data.response.data in this case is an object**
           return data.response.data;
        } else {
          console.log("cant get session info");
        }
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => { }
    );
  }
```

What my understanding is, the `return data.response.data` will not actually return something when the getSessionInfo() is called.

For example, the this.session will still be undefined.

```
  getSession() {
    this.session = this.service.getSessionInfo();
 }
```

What I want to do is, return the value data.response.data and assign it to this.session.

Note, they are in different class in Angular2 Project.

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  service: ApiService;

  session: Object;

  constructor(service: ApiService) {
    this.service = service;
    this.getSession();
  }

  getSession() {
    this.session = this.service.getSessionInfo();

    // I expect this is the true value I expected, not undefined
    console.log(this.session);
  }

}
```

The ApiService class is in a different folder

```
 @Injectable()
    export class ApiService {

      _http: Http;
      regions: Object;
   constructor(http: Http) {
    this._http = http;
  }

    getSessionInfo() {
    .......
  }
}
```

I used to know they can do what I want using $q, $defer, but what should I do using Angular 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do return create either `new Promise`/`Observable` as you are going to use `.subscribe` over observable. So `this._http.get(someCorrectUrlHere)` promise from `getSessionInfo` method and then do have `.then` with `Arrow function` over `getSessionInfo` method.

```
getSessionInfo() {
  //creating custom promise & then resolving and rejecting it on condition.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    this._http.get(someCorrectUrlHere)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.response.statusCode === 200) {
          resolve(data.response.data); //returning data by resolving promise
        } else {
          console.log("cant get session info");
          reject("Error occured");
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      },
      () => {}
    );
  });
}
```

**Code**

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  service: ApiService;
  session: Object;
  constructor(service: ApiService) {
    this.service = service;
    this.getSession();
  }

  getSession() {
    this.service.getSessionInfo().then(
    //success function.
    (session) => {
        this.session = session;
        console.log(session);
    }, 
    (error)=>{
       //error function
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It says 'Property then do not exist on type Subscription'

Comment: , thanks now I am using your approach in my project! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to know you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Observable returned by Angular 2 http call to Promise if you are comfortable working with that

```
getSessionInfo() {
    return this._http.get(someCorrectUrlHere).toPromise();
);
```

More about it in the official Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises).

Or, you can try to do it Angular 2 way. Keeping your service as

```
getSessionInfo() {
    this._http.get(someCorrectUrlHere)
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

and subscribing in your HeaderComponent

```
getSession() {
    this.service.getSessionInfo().subscribe(
    data => {
        if (data.response.statusCode === 200) {
           this.session = data.response.data; 
           console.log(this.session);
        } else {
           console.log("cant get session info");
        }
     },
     err => console.log(err),
     () => { }
   );
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add return inside getSessionInfo() ?

Comment: I guess. I didn't look  into the details. I just suggested two approaches you can take. Look at the docs link that I added.